# R: install uroot package in ubuntu

Tags: r

I am trying to install the forecast package which depends on uroot, which apparently have been written to require a GPU?

`install.packages("uroot")` yields the following error. Has anyone found this issue and may suggest a work around? I am using ubuntu 16.04.

I have the file in question located here: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/ and I added to my path export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/:$PATH

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/rstudio2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/uroot/libs/uroot.so':
  libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/rstudio2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/uroot’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘uroot’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: As with most other questions on SO about "cannot open shared object file", this is likely caused by a missing package. An [ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libcudart.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any) suggests you may need to (re)install `nvidia-cuda-dev`.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and the file is there. I added this to my question.

Comment: @javlacalle adding....just in case

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but are you certain that `PATH` is sufficient? Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67781/176511

Comment: It probably wasn't there because it hadn't been installed in an R package library.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this is useful for someone, I stumbled with the same problem trying to install "imputeTS" with R version 3.5.1 on Fedora 27 with CUDA 10.0 correctly installed an setted in PATH.

for me it just happened that I was running `install.package("imputeTS")` (which depends on `forecast`) in a R console as root, installing the packages to the user home solved the problem. It's seems that the libraries are searched in different places according to the user running the script, it's important to note that.

Answer (score 0):

I just migrated to Linux. On an Ubuntu 18.04 setup, using install.packages with dependencies set to TRUE succeeded with no complaints. (No GPU on mu box.)

```
install.packages("forecast", dep=TRUE)
# there are quite a few dependencies and you happened to be missing one

packageDescription()
#-----------includes this line----------
Imports: colorspace, fracdiff, ggplot2 (>= 2.2.1), graphics, lmtest,
          magrittr, nnet, parallel, Rcpp (>= 0.11.0), stats,
             timeDate, tseries, urca, uroot, zoo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify file "/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf", add "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" env, like:

```
rsession-ld-library-path=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

Actually, When you open session of "RStudio Server" from browser, the session does't get env from the ".bashrc".